# An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request. ASPNETcore and React

Tags: reactjs

I made a new project in asp.netcore version 3.1 and react in visual studio. I get the following when I run the project:

[image: result]

I tried to delete node_modules and ran npm install, but it did not work. I have also tried to clone my friends github repo (which works on his computer) to mine computer to check if it is possible to run, but it does not work. Hoping for an answer as soon as possible.

I have done several projects in aspnet core and jquery. But it does not work to run a project in react, why do I get this error?